# Getting the XML without the <?xml ...?> from minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I've used minidom to create an XML and it comes out correctly but I need it to be returned without the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the beginning. Is there a way to get the XML without the `<?xml?>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i just slice off the first 22 Chars

```
xml_out = doc.toxml()
return xml_out[22:]
```

Comment: That was the solution I ended up using just wanted to know if there was a way to do it without the brute force approach.

Comment: tbh, for minidom, this is the easiest way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

You can try slicing the string at the first instance of `?>`:

```
xml = xml[xml.index('?>') + 2:]
```

---

I looked at the source code of the `xml.dom.minidom` package and I think this will do the job as well:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

def writexml(self, writer, indent="", addindent="", newl="", encoding = None):
  for node in self.childNodes:
    node.writexml(writer, indent, addindent, newl)

xml.dom.minidom.Document.writexml = writexml

del writexml
```

Comment: Yeah for now I'm removing it manually by taking a substring, but was just wondering if there was a way to generate it without the xml tag at the top.